# Recreating the zoom in/out buttons in a non-Leaflet application (Sigma JS)?

Tags: html, css, leaflet

I have a webpage that contains both a network graph created with Sigma JS (http://sigmajs.org/) and a Leaflet map that corresponds to the network graph.  The network graph has similar functionality to a Leaflet map in that you can drag the screen around and, more to the point, zoom in and out using click buttons.

I would like my page to have a more cohesive look and I would therefore like the zoom in and out buttons on my network graph to look the same as the buttons on the Leaflet map.  I like the look of the Leaflet buttons, so what I would like to do is recreate the Leaflet buttons in my network graph.
Obviously, I could duplicate the buttons from the ground up and just make all the CSS needed to design the buttons myself.  But I am an html/CSS n00b, so I was thinking a more efficient way would be to find the CSS that leaflet uses to create the buttons and copy it into the Sigma JS CSS.

My problem is that I can’t seem to locate all of the CSS used.  I guess it’s also possible that, given I am new to this, there is something else going on that is designing the buttons apart from the CSS.  Here is what I have found so far at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.css, which is where I would have thought everything needed for the zoom buttons would be located.  I guess I don't know where the plus and minus signs come from, among other things:

```
        font: bold 18px 'Lucida Console', Monaco, monospace;
        text-indent: 1px;
        border: 2px dotted #38f;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use leaflet and sigmajs on the same site and thus the leaflet css in loaded anyways, just create buttons using the existing classes:

```
<div class="leaflet-control leaflet-bar">
    <a class="leaflet-control-zoom-in" href="#" title="Zoom in">+</a>
    <a class="leaflet-control-zoom-in" href="#" title="Zoom out">-</a>
</div>
```

(as you can see the + and - are not created with css but in the html)

If you haven't loaded the leaflet.css on your page, just find and copy the classes I used below from the leaflet.css to your css file.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Krxldfx/jskftten/).